# Is there any other way to install firmware than recovery mode or flash tool?

Tags: device-firmware

I'm trying to re-install my phone stock firmware. (I'm experiencing bugs, I already factory reset 5 times but the bugs are still there)

Phone's chipset is spreadtrum (sc8830)

I already loaded the packet file succesfully as seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx19D.jpg).

The problem is.... I can't put my phone into `download mode` (bug), now the tool can't detect it.

I as well already tried all of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCERT.jpg) option but still nothing.

Another bug is I can't put it into `recovery mode`. I tried using apps like link2sd to put it into recovery mode but it only goes to blank screen (tried that many times)

Is there any other way to install firmware than what I stated above?

Comment: [here's](http://www.yugatech.com/mobile/skk-announces-aura-edge-for-php1999/) the link for the phone's details.

Comment: The loaded PAC file seems different from your device Chipset: it's says SC7731, yours is SC8830.

Answer (score 1):

Spreadtrum devices don't have recoveries, nor don't they have a ''download mode". Their bootloader is accessed with a "boot key" (usually hardware buttons) through **SCI USB2Serial** port.

To get the phone detected, just simply switch it off. Hold volume down button (or volume up) and plug the device to the computer. Windows should install drivers (Download and install [SCI drivers](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-827.html)).

Open the flash tool (ResearchDownload), load the PAC file, click on run. Power off the device, hold volume up/ down, connect USB cable. Et voilà.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know these basic things first.

1. Factory Reset doesn't fix bugs
2. Your phone is not having recovery installed.
3. Your phone recovery and download option is installed in hardware it is nothing to do with your firmware.

Download the application called as [Power Menu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.littlevictor.powermenu) and then try going into download mode.

If you are having a rooted Android phone then you can flash stock firmware with the help of FlashFire

There is a detail instructions given about the [way to use FlashFire on your Android](https://xtremetricks.net/backup-restore-via-adb-over-wi-fi-using-flashfire/) phone.